# Gradle war command not including hibernate cfg file

Tags: gradle

Hibernate-cfg.xml not added to war classes folder.I am using below script to deploy web applcation to tomcat.After copy, when i am starting tomcat , gettign below error
    eNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved URL because it does not exist

apply plugin: 'java'
        apply plugin: 'war'
        sourceCompatibility = 1.7
        apply plugin: 'eclipse'
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {

```
        compile("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
        compile("org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.3.RELEASE")
        compile("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.3.RELEASE")
        compile("org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.3.RELEASE")
        compile("org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.3.RELEASE")
         compile("org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.0.3.RELEASE")
         compile("org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.3.RELEASE")
         compile("org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.3.RELEASE")
         compile("org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.3.RELEASE")
         compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.3.RELEASE")
         compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.3.RELEASE")
         compile("org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.0.0")
         compile("antlr:antlr:2.7.7")
         compile("commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1")
         compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final")
          compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.5.Final")
           compile("org.apache.derby:derbyclient:10.12.1.1")  
           compile("javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA") 
            compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5")



    }
    task deploy (dependsOn: war){
        copy {
            from "build/libs"
            into "C:/soft/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/webapps"
            include "*.war"
        }
    }
    /*task startTomcat(dependsOn:deploy,type:Exec) {
        workingDir  "C:/mdi/soft/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/bin"
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'startup.bat'
    }*/
    task startTomcat << {
       def processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(['cmd','/c','startup.bat'])
       processBuilder.directory(new File("C:/soft/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/bin"))
       processBuilder.start()
    }
    // Set source directory
    // War file name
    war
    {
    war.baseName = 'userregisteration'

    project.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'
    sourceSets{

            main {

                java {

                    srcDir 'src'


                     }

                 }
               }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your war task add a from closure:

```
from(<directory containing Hibernate-cfg.xml>){
    into <'directory in the war in which you'd like the file to be placed'>
    include 'Hibernate-cfg.xml'
}
```

This is also pretty basic. I'd recommend perhaps reviewing the Gradle manual again to gain a better understanding of working with files.

Comment: i have found solution by creating hibernate cfg file in resources folder.

Comment: // Set source directory
war{
project.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'
sourceSets{

        main {

            java {

                srcDir 'src'
                  }

            resources {
                     srcDir 'resources'
                   }
              }
                 
           }           
 }